# How to use lib in test directory which is outside of src in rust?

Tags: rust

I have a following folder structure,

```
.
├── utils/
│   ├── helpers.rs
│   └── lib.rs
├── tests/
│   └── helpers.rs
└── Cargo.toml
```

`lib.rs` just includes `helpers.rs`,

```
mod helpers;
```

So how do use `utils::helpers` inside `tests/helpers.rs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tests` folder contains your *integration* tests. Those tests may only use the public interface of your library, and not test internals that are hidden to a user of your library.

If you want your users to use `utils::helpers`, then make sure that it is `pub`lic and write integration tests from the downstream developers perspective. However, if you only want to write unit tests (which is much more likely), then add them in the `helpers` module itself.

See ["Test Organization" in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html) for more information.